# Spring Boot Test not rolling back transactions (MS SQL Server, Spring Boot 2.7.5)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, transactions

I am writing integration tests for a project with multiple datasources and want to test the repository and service layer. Problem is that the @Transactional annotation is not working and data inserted during tests is persisted.

This is a simple IT. I need to use @SpringBootTest instead of @DataJpaTest because multiple datasources are configured in a bean which handles assigning the right datasource to the correct repository.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MyApp.class, TestSecurityConfiguration.class })
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("database-test")
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class MyIT {


    @Autowired
    ChannelRepository channelRepository;

    @Test
    public void testChannels() {

        Channel testChannel1 = new Channel();
        testChannel1.setDescription("Test Channel 1");
        channelRepository.save(testChannel1);

        Channel testChannel2 = new Channel();
        testChannel2.setDescription("Test Channel 2");
        channelRepository.save(testChannel2);

        Channel channel = channelRepository.findById(1).get();
        assertThat(channel).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

The dialect configured in the application.yml is "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" and the database is our test database that runs on a dedicated server, not an embedded database.

The data is inserted without rollback.

Comment: If you have multiple datasource you also have multiple transactions which will be commit for each individually (or even worse you have unmanaged transactions and you hope they work). I also wonder how you are assigning the dataasource as this looks like you are working with just a single default repository.

Comment: I didn't code the DatabaseConfig Beans but I works by having multiple @Configuration DatabaseConfig beans that scan different packages. This is how the JPA repositories know which EntityManager to use.

Comment: But in this test you are only using one. Hence you aren't switching datasources but just a single one, in this test. So why not just use `@DataJpaTest` as your comment doesn't really hold.

Comment: There are also some other beans that I need. I found the problem now but have no solution atm. When I call save(), JpaTransactionManager creates a new inner transaction, saves the entity and closes the transaction. I don't know why though.

Comment: Because you are probably using another tx manager and thus there is no transaction. Multiple entitymanagers means multiple tx managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the JpaTransactionManager logs using:

```
logging:
  level:
    sql: DEBUG
    ROOT: DEBUG
    org.springframework.orm.jpa: DEBUG
    org.springframework.transaction: DEBUG
```

I saw that for each .save() call there was a new inner transaction. I tried to specify the transaction manager manually by passing the value to the @Transactional annotation and now it works. Looks like the DataSource beans are not picked up entirely correct. I got the idea based on this article where a ChainedTransactionManager is used for multiple datasources https://medium.com/preplaced/distributed-transaction-management-for-multiple-databases-with-springboot-jpa-and-hibernate-cde4e1b298e4